# IndexOutOfRangeException Was Unhandled warning

Tags: c#, csv

I have implemented some code in order to make changes to my csv file. However every time I run the program I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` error.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "kaviaReport 02_08_2016.csv");
        var fileContents = ReadFile(filePath);

        foreach (var line in fileContents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();
        int lineCounter = 0;
        string currentLine = string.Empty;
        var target = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        //.Skip(1) // Skip the line with column names
        while ((currentLine = fileName) != null)//while there are lines to read
        {
            if (lineCounter != 0)
            {
                //If it's not the first line
                var lineElements = currentLine.Split(',');//split your fields into an array
                lineElements[4] = lineElements[4].Replace(' ', ',');//replace the space in position 4(field 5) of your array
                //target.WriteAllLines(string.Join(",", fielded));//write the line in the new file
                File.WriteAllLines(fileName, target);
            }

            lineCounter++;

        }

        return results;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please refine your question a bit and don't let us do all the work.
See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does the answer was helpful to solve an error?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do but the problem is here:

```
lineElements[4] = lineElements[4].Replace(' ', ',');
```

You don't have 5 elements in array `lineElements`

Your `filePath` variable containts `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "kaviaReport 02_08_2016.csv");`. So it should be something like: `C:\Project\Bin\kaviaReport 02_08_2016.csv`

Then you pass it into `ReadFile()` as a `fileName`

After that in the line

```
while ((currentLine = fileName) != null)
```

you set to `currentLine`  the same values as `fileName` and check it on `NULL`. So now you have 2 variables with the same value. Then you split value (like: `C:\Project\Bin\kaviaReport 02_08_2016.csv`) by `,`. As you can see there is no any `,` in your path. As a result you get array `lineElements` with only one element with index **0**. But you try to get element by index **4**.

```
lineElements[4] = lineElements[4].Replace(' ', ',');
```

So as expected you got **IndexOutOfRangeException**